# How I can to check if a Const is containing in a List in Z3Py?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

In Z3Py, I need to check if a Const type is containing in a List, I define the Datatype List and the Const, I tried to use the method Contain (https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#ada058544efbae7608acaef3233aa4422) but it only is available for string datatype and I need for all.

```
def funList(sort):
    List = Datatype('List')
    #insert: (Int, List) -> List
    List.declare('insert', ('head', sort), ('tail', List)) 
    List.declare('nil')
    return List.create() 

IntList = funList(IntSort())
l1 = Const('l1', IntList)
```

I tried to do a loop in Z3 but it doesn't work :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear. Are you trying to code up some sort of list membership? (Like finding an element in a list.)

If this is your goal, I'd recommend against using a `Datatype` based coding. Because any function you'll write on that (like `elem`, `length`, etc.) will have to be recursive. And SMT solvers don't do well with recursive definitions of that form; as it puts the logic into the undecidable fragment. Furthermore, debugging and coding is rather difficult when recursive types like these are present as the tool support isn't that great.

If your goal is to use list-like structures, I'd recommend using the built-in `sequence` logic instead. Here's an example:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

# declare a sequence of integers
iseq = Const('iseq', SeqSort(IntSort()))

# assert 3 is somewhere in this sequence
s.add(Contains(iseq, Unit(IntVal(3))))

# assert the sequence has at least 5 elements
s.add(Length(iseq) >= 5)

# get a model and print it:
if s.check() == sat:
    print s.model()
```

When I run this, I get:

```
$ python a.py
[iseq = Concat(Unit(9),
               Concat(Unit(10),
                      Concat(Unit(3),
                             Concat(Unit(16), Unit(17)))))]
```

This is a bit hard to read perhaps, but it's essentially saying `iseq` is a sequence that is concatenation (`Concat`) of a bunch of singletons (`Unit`). In more convenient notation, this would be:

```
iseq = [9, 10, 3, 16, 17]
```

And as you can see it has 5 elements and `3` is indeed this sequence as required by our constraints.

Z3's sequence logic is pretty rich, and it contains many functions that you'd want to perform. See here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3py_8py_source.html#l09944

Comment: Thanks for you help. Respect your question (Are you trying to code up some sort of list membership? (Like finding an element in a list.). Yes I am trying to do it. But in your example with use of sequence, I don't understand how for example I could to know if a list or sequence have the number 3, because in the assert you are forcing it to be part of the sequence, right? That shouldn't return true or false? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You don't have to assert it. `Contains(iseq, Unit(IntVal(3)))` will be a symbolic boolean that if it is true you know `3` is in your list. Just assign it to a boolean and program with it as usual. i.e., `b = Contains(iseq, Unit(IntVal(3)))`, then `b` is symbolic value true if `3` is in `iseq`.

Comment: True, thanks. If I would to use the method Empty, how I could to use it? Because I try to prove ```s.add(Empty(iseq) == False) ```but it back "Z3Exception: Non-sequence, non-regular expression sort passed to Empty" then I don't know how I could to solve it. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: `Empty` takes a sort and returns an empty sequence (list if you will) of that sort. It does not check for emptiness. For that, use `Length(iseq) == 0`.

Comment: Also, stack-overflow works best if questions are well-contained and comments shouldn't be for new questions but only clarifications. If your original query is answered, please mark this question as "accepted answer" (by using the checkmark), and ask a new question. This helps the community and others who might have similar questions.